# I want to create image intervention

Tags: image, laravel, intervention

For user profile I want to create profile picture, but when I write composer require intervention/image in terminal I get this error:

```
- intervention/image 2.4.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
- intervention/image 2.4.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
- Installation request for intervention/image ^2.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.0, 2.4.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\AppServ\php5\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i deleted extension=php.dll from php.ini

Comment: I uncommented it.

Comment: Try doing what the message suggests, install fileinfo PHP extension.

Answer (score 1):

Read what Composer suggests. Just install the PHP extenion fileinfo. Check the installation guide on PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the php_fileinfo.dll in your php/ext folder. Then uncomment this line in your php.ini

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```